# Debug postfix messes up linking SDL2 with CMake

Tags: c, cmake

I am trying to set up a project with the SDL2 library using CMake. When i compile for release everything works fine. However when setting the build type to debug compilation fails with the following error:

```
*** No rule to make target 'Lib/SDL2/libSDL2d.a', needed by '../Bin/Template'.  Stop.
```

It seems like SDL2 adds a postfix for debug builds and that messes things up.

This is the CMakeLists.txt im using:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)

project(Template)

add_subdirectory(Lib/SDL2)

# C Standard
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# compile with debug info
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

# output directories
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Bin)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Bin)

# build directory
set(CMAKE_BUILD_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Build)

include_directories(
    Source
    Lib/SDL2/include
)

set(SOURCES 
    Source/main.c
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2-static)
```

I don't want to use find_packge and include the SDL2 source code directly into my project.

What do i need to change to be able to compile for debug?

Comment: Did the debug library `Lib/SDL2/libSDL2d.a` even build? Is it located where it should be?

Comment: @squareskittles it compiles the target SDL2-static and i have a libSDL2.a in my Build directory.

Comment: Unless you are building for Android, it would seem the SDL2 CMake code appends a `d` to the library name of the Debug library when built (see [here](https://github.com/davidsiaw/SDL2/blob/6ecaa6b61372e5b2f9bd01201814d07e34bb4186/CMakeLists.txt#L1777)). So when you build in Debug configuration, the built SDL2 library is `Build/libSDL2.a` with the `d` postfix missing?

Comment: @squareskittles Yes. The library file lacks the postfix d. I am building for Linux.

Comment: @squareskittles That was indeed the error. Post it as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDL2 code should add the postfix `d` to the built library name when `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set to Debug (see the SDL2 code snippet [here](https://github.com/davidsiaw/SDL2/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L1777)). What appears to be the issue here is the *placement* of the line:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

in your CMake file. You probably initially built this in the Release configuration. But when switching it to Debug, the change is not applied to SDL2 because `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set **after** traversing to the `Lib/SDL2` directory. You can correct this by moving the `set()` command before the call to `add_subdirectory()`:

```
# Set the build type first!
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
add_subdirectory(Lib/SDL2)
```

***You can avoid these issues by setting the build configuration at the command line instead***, which is the more common and accepted CMake convention:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

Comment: "You can avoid these issues by setting the build configuration at the command line instead" -- this should be the focal point of the answer, ideally in **BIG BOLD LETTERS**.